# Create element / resource with dynamic fields in react admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

we store points of interest (POI) in our data base and decide between several classes like:

- lake
- airport
- port
- ...

All these classes should be treated as single resource since 90% of their properties are the same (long, lat, name ...). The challenge, we are facing, is that lake and port should have a depth as property but the airport shouldn't.

The fields shown in a create view should chance, when the user selects e.g. lake as POI type.

What would be the aproriate way to create a front-end and the react resource including create, edit and list views in react admin?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples in documentation that can help you: [Linking Two Inputs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs)

The solution may look something like this:

```
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form'
import { Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, NumberInput, SelectInput } from 'react-admin'

const CreatePOI = (props) => {
  const { values } = useFormState()

  const choices={[
    { id: 'lake', name: 'Lake' },
    { id: 'airport', name: 'Airport' },
    { id: 'port', name: 'Port' },
  ]}
  
  return (
    <Create {...rest} >
      <SimpleForm
        <TextInput source="name" />                       
        <SelectInput source="type" choices={choices} />             
        { values.type === 'lake' || values.type === 'port' ? <NumberInput source="depth" /> : null }
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )  
}
```